# How to access the object declared in the method?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

How to access the object declared in the method using powermock-mockito ?

For example :

```
Class A 
{

private void method1()
{
  B b = new B();
  // This method returns nothing , and I have no intention to change it's return type or  //any other things.
}

}

Class B {

public B()
{

}

}
```

Now I am writing the test case which calls this private method , in my test case I want to get the values of object B created in method1 .(PowerMock-Mockito)

Comment: I'm not sure it's even possible. Since your method doesn't return anything it should somehow change state of `A`, I'd assume. Why don't you test this?

Comment: can't powermock manage this for users ? :)

Comment: Have you considered reading up on their documentation? They go through many sample use cases here: http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the Object B, as its scope is over once the method is executed and it will be elligible for garbage collection if no more references are there.Try declaring the variable in class level and initialise in your method. Then you can use reflection to get the Object. If you are using spring ReflectionTestUtils is a handy class to achieve this.

Comment: Yes but powermock seems to have api called whenNew , I mean mocking the construction of the object and then get the value, isn't it possible by that way

Comment: Not sure if you can get the created object with whenNew